# How to split dataset into K-fold without loading the whole dataset at once?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, k-fold

I can't load all of my dataset at once, so I used `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` in order to load batches of images during training. It works well if I want to split my dataset into 2 subsets (train and validation), however, I'd like to divide my dataset into K-folds in order to make cross validation. (5 folds would be nice)

How can I make K-folds without loading my whole dataset ?
Do I have to give up using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I recommend that you switch to `tf.data.Dataset()`.

Not only is it more efficient but it gives you more flexibility in terms of what you can implement.

Say you have images(`image_paths`) and `labels` as an example.

In that way, you could create a pipeline like:

```
training_data = []
validation_data = []
kf = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=42)
for train_index, val_index in kf.split(images,labels):
    X_train, X_val = images[train_index], images[val_index]
    y_train, y_val = labels[train_index], labels[val_index]
    training_data.append([X_train,y_train])
    validation_data.append([X_val,y_val])
```

Then you could create something like:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(training_data):
    x_train, y_train = training_data[index][0], training_data[index][1]
    x_valid, y_valid = validation_data[index][0], validation_data[index][1]
   
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(mapping_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    
    
    validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(mapping_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)



    model.fit(train_dataset,
             validation_data=validation_dataset,
             epochs=epochs,
             verbose=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So I should put images path in the variable 'images' and then load them in the mapping_function ?

Comment: Exactly. The mapping function as a logic should have methods such as image = tf.io.decode_jpg(image_path,channels=3) etc.

Comment: Or other processing that you would like to implement :D