# PyTable table split

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, hdf5, pytables

I have a PyTable table like the following format:

```
/neg/data.cols (Cols), 5 columns
  data (Column(8909, 256, 256), ('<f4', (256, 256)))
  filename (Column(8909,), |S100)
  id (Column(8909,), uint32)
  label (Column(8909,), uint8)
  offset (Column(8909,), float64)
```

There is 8909 data within the table and corresponding labels. I want to split this table into train tests for machine learning. Let's say keep 80% rows as training data and 20% as the test.

Is there any utility function that can help me to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What are your desired data objects after splitting the table into train and test datasets? 1 NumPy array for each set? Or 4 arrays: train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels? (or something else?).

If you are using Keras, there are some other answers posted on StackOverflow that are related to loading batches. They might be helpful. I am sharing links as a reference. Read my answer below you want to code yourself.

For Keras batch loading:  [Keras: load images batch wise for large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200743/10462884) and [How to split dataset into K-fold without loading the whole dataset at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67058583/10462884) If that doesn't help, Google "keras fit_generator" for some tutorials. You will need to write a Python generator function to read and load image arrays from your H5 file.

**My answer:**
Typically you want to read random rows from the Table. The code below shows how to do that with the `Table.read_coordinates()` function. It is a standalone example that creates a sample HDF5 file that matches your data schema (same group and dataset layout). It closes the file after it creates the data, then opens 'read-only' to access the data.

The read process first creates 2 lists of random and unique row numbers (`test_list` and `train_list`), then uses them to read the row data into various arrays as described above. The 'read-only' part should work "as-is" with your data (just need to change the filename). Once you have the arrays, you can pass them to train and test your model.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np
import random

nrows = 8000
size = 100
ds_dt = np.dtype( [ ('data',(float,(size,size))), ('filename','S100'),
                 ('id',int), ('label',int), ('offset',float) ] )

# Create sample data for use below    
with tb.File('SO_70014301.h5','w') as h5f:
    data_table = h5f.create_table('/neg','data',description=ds_dt,createparents=True)
    for cnt in range(nrows):
        arr = np.random.random(size*size).reshape(size,size)
        data_list = [ (arr, str(f'filename_{cnt+1:003}.jpg'), cnt+1, cnt+1001, 10.*cnt), ] 
        data_table.append(data_list)

# read sample data and extract Table: '/neg/data' aka file.root.neg.data
with tb.File('SO_70014301.h5','r') as h5f:
    data_table = h5f.root.neg.data
    nrows = data_table.nrows
    #create lists with row ids to extract test and training data
    row_list = list(range(nrows))
    test_list = sorted(random.sample(row_list, k=int(0.20*nrows)))
    train_list = list(set(row_list) - set(test_list))
    print(len(row_list),len(test_list),len(train_list))   

    #extract entire training dataset to np.recarray
    train_arr = data_table.read_coordinates(train_list)
    print(train_arr.shape)
    print(train_arr.dtype)

    #extract entire test dataset to np.recarray
    test_arr = data_table.read_coordinates(test_list)
    print(test_arr.shape)
    print(test_arr.dtype)
    
    # extract training data to array
    train_data = data_table.read_coordinates(train_list,field='data')
    # extract training labels to array
    train_labs = data_table.read_coordinates(train_list,field='label')
    print(train_data.shape, train_data.dtype)
    print(train_labs.shape, train_labs.dtype)
    
    # extract test data to array
    test_data = data_table.read_coordinates(test_list,field='data')
    # extract test labels to array
    test_labs = data_table.read_coordinates(test_list,field='label')
    print(test_data.shape, test_data.dtype)
    print(test_labs.shape, test_labs.dtype)
```